# Change css to a link onclick, three different styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the css assigned to a link onclick, assuming I have 3 styles

```
<a href='#' id='but' class='style1'>link</a>

style1{color:red;}
style2{color:blue;}
style3{color:green;}
```

if the current style is style1 change to style2; if current is style2 change to style3; if current is style3 change to style1; and work in that loop.

Is that possible?

Comment: _"Is that possible?"_ Yes. But if you're looking for _how_ it's possible you should show what you tried first that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

```
var a = document.getElementById('but');
var styles = ["style1","style2","style3"];
var i = 0;              
a.onclick = function(){
  i = (i+1)%3;
  this.className = styles[i];
};
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpR9j/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
var element = document.getElementById('but');
if(hasClass(element, 'style1')) {
   element.className = 'style2';
} else if(hasClass(element, 'style2')){
   element.className = 'style3';
} else if(hasClass(element, 'style3')){
   element.className = 'style1';
}
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

Put that in a function and you are good to go.

Comment: @ZachSaucier, where am I using jQuery here?